# Modify exception data while logging with NLog

Tags: c#, exception, logging, nlog

I have a global try/catch around my application methods to log unhandled exceptions and show an error message. For logging I use NLog. If I handle an exception and log it manually I set a key 'logged' in the exceptions data object to prevent the second log from the global try/catch.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Application stuff            
            SomeMethod();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.Data['logged'] == false)
            {
                logger.Error(ex, "A unhandled exception occured.")
                ex.Data['logged'] = true;
            }

            // Show error dialog
        }
    }

    public static void SomeMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            // Method stuff
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex, "A handled exception occured.")
            ex.Data['logged'] = true;
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to simplify the process so that I don't have to call `ex.Data['logged'] = true;` manually. Is there a way to modify the data property of an exception automatically while logging with NLog? I tried to use a `MethodCall`-Target but I had no access to the exception reference. The exception could only be passed as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Would it work for you to use NLog to perhaps modify your approach to logging exceptions slightly?

```
public partial class App
{
    private static Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            SomeMethod();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.ErrorEx(ex, "message");
        }
    }

    public static void SomeMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            // Method stuff
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.ErrorEx(ex, "A handled exception occured.");
            throw;
        }
    }
}

public static class NLogExt
{
    public static void ErrorEx(this NLog.Logger logger, Exception ex, string message)
    {
        if (ex.Data["logged"] as bool? == true) return;
        logger.Error(ex, message);
        ex.Data.Add("logged", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also thought of this, but I had to override 15 overloads per log level. I'll keep that in mind but hope for a more compact solution.